# Flask SocketIO Not Properly Sending the Event Type on an emit call

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am running into issues getting my socket.io client to receive a message with a custom event type properly from my server.

I am emitting a request to get the client's user id from my server when a client successfully connects. After difficulties when trying to use sessions between HTTP requests and WebSockets, I switched over to passing the user id through the templating with jinja.

However, I am now having trouble getting the client to receive a custom type packet from the server.

**controller.py**

```py
@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    hello = 'Hello'
    emit('get_user', hello, include_self=True)
    socketio.sleep(0)
    return
```

**index.html***

```html
<script>
const socket = io(SERVER_URL/PATH);

socket.on("get_user", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit("send_user", {{ user.id }});
</script>
```

The server is showing that it is "emitting" a message with the proper type, but then immediately after it sends it as a Message.

[Server Terminal Logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Oke.png)

The client then only receives the sent message of type `"message"` instead of type `"get_user"`

[Client socket logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzEg5.png)

The question is: How can I get the emit to work properly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: Posting the remainder of the code.

**controllers.py**

```py
# Import flask dependencies
from flask import Blueprint, request, render_template, flash, g, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_socketio import send, emit

# Import the database class for the app
from app import db, socketio

# Import module models
from app.mod_auth.models import User, Socket
from app.mod_home.models import Topic

# Define blueprint for home and set the url prefix
mod_home = Blueprint("home", __name__, url_prefix='/home')

@mod_home.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    print('-----route------\n%r\n-------------------' % session['user_id'])
    # check if user is logged in
    if (not 'user_id' in session) or (session['user_id'] == None):
        return redirect(url_for('auth.signin'))

    user_id = session['user_id']

    # Use the user id to retreive the user's friends list
    user = User.query.get(user_id)
    friends = user.friends.all()

    # Use the user id to retreive the chats that they belong to

    # Retreive a list of the top topics show first 10

    return render_template("home/homepage.html", user=user, friends=friends)

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    # Reply back to client that connection was successful
    hello = 'Hello'
    emit('get_user', hello,
        include_self=True)
    socketio.sleep(0)
    return

@socketio.on('send_user')
def register_user(user):
    print(user)

    # user_id = session['user_id']
    # socket_id = request.sid
    #
    # # Create socket entry
    # socket = Socket(user_id, socket_id)
    #
    # # Add and Commit socket entry
    # db.session.add(socket)
    # db.session.commit()
```

**homepage.html**

```html
<head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
    const socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:5000/home');

    socket.on("get_user", function (data) {
      console.log("received connection_succeeded");
      console.log(data);
      socket.emit("send_user", {{ user.id }});
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The logs all look correct. You are confusing "type" with "event name". When you send an event the "message" packet is used. The first element in the payload of the message is the event name, and the remaining items are the event arguments. So your logs all look good, and it appears as if the client received the `get_user` event. Would you be able to provide a complete example instead of just snippets? That might help me figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Hello Miguel, it's really exciting for me that you responded. Big fan of all your work with flask. I posted the remainder of the code. It appears that my client is not processing the `get_user` by event name and then logging the proper messages nor emitting the `send_user` event back to the server.

Comment: Thanks, I did not even need to run the code, see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing up different namespaces.

When your client connects, it requests the `/home` namespace (do not confuse the Socket.IO namespace with your URL prefix, nothing to do with each other other than both being `/home`). Every time a namespace is connected, the default namespace `/` is connected as well. This generates some confusion, unfortunately, and it is what's causing your problem.

Your server has a connect event handler for `/`, but not for `/home`. Because you are handling the connect on `/`, the `emit()` also goes out on `/`. Your client, however, will only process events for `/home` since that is how you made the connection.

The solution is to use the same namespace everywhere. If you want my advice, I have seen people trip on namespaces so much that these days I prefer to work on the default namespace. So change your connection URL to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and then I think you'll be fine.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you so much, Miguel!